# Recommendation for Petri Nets modelling software?

Tags: software-recommendation

I'm looking for a Petri Nets simulator with a graphical editor for Ubuntu.

Does anyone know if there exists such a tool?

Answer (score 2):

Try out this:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/pipe2/

Comment: Tested. Did some basic testings and works as it is supposed to. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

[Tapaal](https://launchpad.net/~tapaal-packaging/+archive/tapaal)

Timed-Arc Petri Net (TAPN) is a time extension of the classical Petri net model
<..>
The TAPAAL tool offers a graphical editor for drawing TAPN models,
simulator for experimenting with the designed nets and a verification 
environment that automatically answers logical queries formulated in a 
subset of CTL logic (essentially EF, EG, AF, AG formulae without nesting). 
It also allows the user to check whether a given net is k-bounded 
for a given number k. The verification algorithm translates the 
TAPAAL queries into UPPAAL ones and relies on the UPPAAL verification 
engine, but the user does not have to leave the TAPAAL GUI during 
any phase of the model verification and error traces are displayed 
directly in TAPAAL.

[image]

(TAPAAL Screenshot (on Ubuntu 10.10))

Installation:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tapaal-packaging/tapaal`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install tapaal`

**edit:** Tapaal can now be found on [http://www.tapaal.net](http://www.tapaal.net/introduction)

Comment: Tested. Works. It is based on PIPE2. Thank you for the answer.